# Where is sdformat.org?

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

As linked from [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/sdformat), the documentation for sdformat is at http://sdformat.org, but that website seems down or non-existent. Is there another site to use?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4530/where-is-sdformat.org?/) by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-09-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-10-02**:
I've never heard of that website, I don't know who added it to bitbucket but I think the link should be removed.

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on 2013-10-02**:
It's Nate's commit, apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I had also noticed that the link was dead. I finally read this page on the Gazebo wiki and it answered pretty well to all my questions:

http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_A_URDF_In_Gazebo

---

Originally posted by [Arn-O](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/416/arn-o/) with karma: 316 on 2013-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-10-02**:
sdformat.org is back up and running.